# Footer not visible

Tags: footer

There may be some error in this page, its an front-page becuase of that I am not able to see the footer 
Website uitechnosoft.com

```
<!--==========================
Intro Section
============================-->
<section id="intro">
    <div class="intro-container">
        <div id="introCarousel" class="carousel  slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators"></ol>
            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                <!-- Slider One -->
                <div class="carousel-item active" style="background-image: url('<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/intro-carousel/1.jpg');">
            <div class="carousel-container">
              <div class="carousel-content">
                <h2>Digital Marketing</h2>
                <p>
                  Brand identity, Web application development, Digital Marketing, UX Design and and Testing Agency
                  <span>Convert Visitors Into Customers And Generate More Sales</span>
                </p>
                <a href="#about" class="btn-get-started scrollto"><img src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/down_arrow.png" alt="arrow" /></a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- END -->
          <!-- Slider Two -->
          <div class="carousel-item" style="background-image: url('<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/intro-carousel/2.jpg');">
            <div class="carousel-container">
              <div class="carousel-content">
                <h2>Website Development</h2>
                <p>
                  Brand identity, Web application development, Digital Marketing, UX Design and and Testing Agency
                  <span>Convert Visitors Into Customers And Generate More Sales</span>
                </p>
                <a href="#about" class="btn-get-started scrollto"><img src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/down_arrow.png" alt="down arrow" /></a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- END -->
          <!-- Slider Three -->
          <div class="carousel-item" style="background-image: url('<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/intro-carousel/3.jpg');">
            <div class="carousel-container">
              <div class="carousel-content">
                <h2>User Expirence Design</h2>
                <p>
                  Brand identity, Web application development, Digital Marketing, UX Design and and Testing Agency
                  <span>Convert Visitors Into Customers And Generate More Sales</span>
                </p>
                <a href="#about" class="btn-get-started scrollto"><img src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/down_arrow.png" /></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- END -->
      <!-- Slider Four -->
     <div class="carousel-item" style="background-image: url('<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/intro-carousel/4.jpg');">
        <div class="carousel-container">
          <div class="carousel-content">
            <h2>Software Testing</h2>
            <p>
              Brand identity, Web application development, Digital Marketing, UX Design and and Testing Agency
              <span>Convert Visitors Into Customers And Generate More Sales</span>
            </p>
            <a href="#about" class="btn-get-started scrollto"><img src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/down_arrow.png" /></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- END -->
      <!-- Slider Five -->
      <div class="carousel-item" style="background-image: url('<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/intro-carousel/5.jpg');">
        <div class="carousel-container">
          <div class="carousel-content">
            <h2>Application Development</h2>
            <p>
              Brand identity, Web application development, Digital Marketing, UX Design and and Testing Agency
              <span>Convert Visitors Into Customers And Generate More Sales</span>
            </p>
            <a href="#about" class="btn-get-started scrollto"><img src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/down_arrow.png" /></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- END -->
      <!-- Slider Six -->
      <div class="carousel-item" style="background-image: url('<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/intro-carousel/6.jpg');">
        <div class="carousel-container">
          <div class="carousel-content">
            <h2>Graphics Design</h2>
            <p>
              Brand identity, Web application development, Digital Marketing, UX Design and and Testing Agency
              <span>Convert Visitors Into Customers And Generate More Sales</span>
            </p>
            <a href="#about" class="btn-get-started scrollto"><img src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/down_arrow.png" /></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
            <!-- END -->
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

```
<!--==========================
  About Us Section
============================-->
```

```
        <header class="section-header">
            <h3 class="left_align">
                <span>All about us </span>
                Our Story
            </h3>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 row">
                    <div class="col-md-8 pull-left">
                        <?php
                        $id = 84;
                        $post = get_post($id);
                        $content = apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content);
                        echo $content;
                        ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 pull-left">
                        <img src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/about/about_img.png" alt="about">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>


    </div>
</section><!-- #about -->


<!--==========================
  Services Section
============================-->
<section id="services">
    <div class="container">

        <header class="section-header wow fadeInUp">
            <h3>
                We help you to Grow your Business
                <span>Complete Web Solution</span>
            </h3>

        </header>

        <div class="row">
            <?php
            $args = array('posts_per_page' => -1,
                'offset' => 1,
                'category' => 2,
                'numberposts' => -1
            );
            $catPost = get_posts($args);
            //$catPost = get_posts(get_cat_ID("homeService"));
            foreach ($catPost as $post) : setup_postdata($post); ?>


                <?php if (has_post_thumbnail($post->ID)): ?>
                    <?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'single-post-thumbnail'); ?>

                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 box wow bounceInUp" data-wow-duration="1.4s">
                        <a href="digitalmarketing.html">
                            <div class="icon"><img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" alt="digitalmarketing"/></div>
                            <h4 class="title"><a href="digitalmarketing.html"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>
                            <div class="description"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
                            <p class="description"><a href="<?php echo get_field('Page_URL'); ?>">Learn More</a></p>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>

    </div>
</section><!-- #services -->

<!--==========================
 Blog Section
============================-->
<section id="blog_container" class="wow fadeIn">
    <div class="container text-center section-header">
        <h3 class="left_align">From Our Blog</h3>
        <?php
       $args1 = array('posts_per_page' => -1,
                'offset' => 1,
                'category' => 9,
                'numberposts' => -1
            );
        $catPost = get_posts($args1);
        //$catPost = get_posts(get_cat_ID("homeService"));
        foreach ($catPost as $post) : setup_postdata($post); ?>


            <?php if (has_post_thumbnail($post->ID)): ?>
                <?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'single-post-thumbnail'); ?>
                <p class="description">
                    <b> <?php the_title(); ?></b>
                    <?php echo strip_tags(get_the_excerpt()); ?>
                </p>
                <img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" alt="blog"/>

                <a class="cta-btn" href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">Read Blog Post</a>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
</section><!-- #career -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you click "View page source" and scroll down you will see that your code is broken in the last line

```
 <p class="description"><a href="
```

It looks like you are trying to call `get_field()` which is Advanced Custom Fields function but it may not exist because the plugin is not loaded. Try enabling the `Advanced Custom Fields` plugin and check again or you can replace the whole line with the WordPress native `get_post_meta()` function.